# How do I make a bootable USB drive for Winodws 7 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

Almost all questions I've found here are outdated. I've already tried using UNetbootin and WINusb and neither have worked. When I used UNetbootin, once I booted the computer from the USB, it was stuck in a continuous loop of counting down from ten until boot, but would never actually boot. When I tried using WINusb I receive an error message when I try to install the ISO onto the USB saying: *Installation failed! Exit code: 256 Log: Formating device... Error:Error opening /dev/sdb: No medium found.* I'm new to the command line so please give all answers with easy directions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

in case YUMI doesn't work - try [universal usb installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

it worked for me always from Windows. Please double check your .iso file whether it has been downloaded properly or not?